# Unable to delete achievement

Tags: facebook-graph-api, curl, facebook-opengraph

When I try to post an achievement I'm getting the error:
({error:{message:"(#3401) Achievement count 1004 exceeds maximum 1000 for this application", type:"OAuthException", code:3401}})

So I'm trying to delete this achievement, using JavaScript post, with the exact same achievement URL, and I'm getting:
({error:{message:"(#3403) Achievement hasn't been registered for this application. See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/achievements/", type:"OAuthException", code:3403}})

Is there a problem with deleting using JavaScript? Cause if I'm trying to do the same this using Curl with the achievement ID instead of the URL, it's working!

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are encoding the URL incorrectly? Open the web inspector and check out the exact post params that are happening. Facebook's server's don't do anything differently for JS vs PHP.